# Glide does not load image from File

Tags: android, android-glide

I am using File picker to get image as File and then I want to load it into ImageView with Glide.

I am trying to use this code, but it fails to load image into image view.

```
Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
      .load(Uri.fromFile(imageFile))
      .error(R.drawable.ic_person_gray)
      .listener(new RequestListener<Uri, GlideDrawable>() {
        @Override public boolean onException(
            Exception e, Uri model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource
        ) {
          Timber.d(e.getMessage());
          return false;
        }

        @Override public boolean onResourceReady(
            GlideDrawable resource,
            Uri model,
            Target<GlideDrawable> target,
            boolean isFromMemoryCache,
            boolean isFirstResource
        ) {
          editProfilePresenter.uploadProfilePicture(imageFile);
          return false;
        }
      })
      .into(ivAvatar);
```

When I do debug, it never reaches debug points inside **onException** or **onResourceReady**.

How I can fix this?

Comment: instead of loading like `Uri.fromFile(imageFile)` just use `load(imageFile.getPath())`.

Comment: I have tried it, but the result is same. It does not load the image with imageFile.getPath.

Comment: You are sure that `getApplicationContext()` returns a valid `context` ?

Answer (score 1):

Use Uri.parse(imageFile.getAbsolutePath())

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an Uri there, you can just get the path of your file, and your listener will look like this
My ex:

```
Glide.with(context).load(yourFile.getAbsolutePath()).centerCrop().listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        spinKitView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        spinKitView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        return false;
                    }
                }).into(ivAvatar);
```

SpinkitView is just a view that shows a loading animation (in case takes time to load the picture)

Comment: With this code, debugger goes into onResourceReady, but it does not show image loaded inside ImageView. Do you know why?

Comment: Try the same code without a listener.. I am guessing it's because of the `context` passed to it . Also, make sure `ivAvatar` is a valid View linked to the XML layout of your activity / fragment

Comment: Yeah, ivAvatar is a valid ImageView. I removed a listener, but still same.

Comment: Well, if still didn't work, and you are sure that `isAvatar` is a valid view (also hope you don't call this before `isAvatar = findViewById(R.id.isAvatar);` ) that means your File is not valid (or there is not image to be loaded)